H20 error in R: Error en .Call(R_curl_fetch_memory, enc2utf8(url), handle, nonblocking): the elapsed time limit has been reached
When I am trying to run the function h2o.splitFrame from H2O, I receive the following error:
Error en .Call(R_curl_fetch_memory, enc2utf8(url), handle, nonblocking): 
  se ha alcanzado el límite de tiempo transcurrido

I tried to check the admin task to liberate the memory from my laptop, and tried other combinations but nothing worked. Find below my complete code.
# Establecer el tiempo de espera de CURL
options(RCurlOptions = list(timeout = 600))

library(h2o)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)

# Detectar el número de núcleos disponibles
n_cores <- parallel::detectCores()
registerDoParallel(cores=4)

# Inicializar H2O con parámetros mejorados
h2o.init(
  ip = "localhost",
  nthreads = max(1, n_cores - 1),
  max_mem_size = "6g"
)

# Deshabilitamos la salida de progreso
h2o.no_progress()

data <- as.h2o(ordata.ren)

splits <- h2o.splitFrame(
  data = data, 
  ratios = c(0.7, 0.15),  # partition data into 70%, 15%, 15% chunks
  destination_frames = c("train", "valid", "test"),  # frame ID (not required)
  seed = 1  # setting a seed will guarantee reproducibility
)

# When I run this part of the code, I receive the error message mentioned before:
# Error en .Call(R_curl_fetch_memory, enc2utf8(url), handle, nonblocking): 
#   se ha alcanzado el límite de tiempo transcurrido.

train <- splits[[1]]
valid <- splits[[2]]
test <- splits[[3]]

y <- "Price"
x <- setdiff(names(data), y)
print(x)


H2O is capable of using curl package instead of RCurl if installed. I would first try to use the curl package (install.packages("curl")) and if that doesn't help, I would like to ask you to provide more information such as H2O version, OS version, processor architecture (x86_64 or M1), total available memory (RAM) on the laptop and free memory, dataset size, dataset metadata (type and cardinality (if applicable) of each column, number of rows, number of columns).
Also feel free to submit a bug report to H2O-3 if installing curl doesn't help. The bug report template should guide you to fill the most important things that we need to find out what went wrong.
